# Find max font-size for dynamic width

Tags: php, javascript, sass

I'm using **SASS/SCSS** and want to create a `@function/@mixin` which will figure the max possible font-size for a container, given a dynamic width.

For example:

```
<body style="font-size: 10px;">
    <div style="width: 960px;"> <!--This width is dynamic-->
        <span style="font-size: 12.3em">Patrick Rocks</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

The unknown variable in this equation is the `font-size` on the `<span>` tag. I set it to 12.3em which would be 123px (relative to the font-size of the `<body>` tag), but that could change depending on `letter-spacing` `font-family` or other aspects. Perhaps because of the complexity of this it would be best served to calculate this with JavaScript, or PHP.

Comment: Can you boil this down to a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it through and found a solution which fits my needs. The solution only works if the following is known.

- The exact text being used
- The font being used
- The default width based on the parent font-size

**DEMO:**
http://wecodesign.com/demos/stackoverflow-7420897.htm

**SCSS:**

```
$logoDefaultWidth: 76; /*Pixels*/

@function getFontSize($newLogoWidth) {
    $fontSize: $newLogoWidth/$logoDefaultWidth;
    @return #{$fontSize}em;
}
@function pxToEm($px) {
    @return #{$px/10}em;
}
body {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.logo {
    width: pxToEm($logoDefaultWidth);
}
.logo.s960 {
    font-size: getFontSize(960);
}
.logo.s480 {
    font-size: getFontSize(480);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="logo s960">Patrick Rocks</div>
<div class="logo s480">Patrick Rocks</div>
```

**TODO:**

This solution has a known issue with WebKit (Chrome/Safari) browers. WebKit browsers render @font-face font's much thicker than they should, thus making the $logoDefaultWidth incorrect. I'm working on trying to find out how to stop WebKit from making the font so thick, or on a separate calculation for WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this on the server side, as the user's font may have any dimensions. You'll have to do it in javascript, in the browser.

Comment: I'm providing my own font with @fontface, with that, would I be able to do something server-side? I found an example using Java and some libraries which detect a bunch of stuff about a font's dimensions; however, I'm using PHP and haven't found anything so far.

Comment: As you've seen, even with @fontface, the width of the font depend on the rendering engine, user settings (hinting, etc), etc